# TensorFlow shuffle_batch not working

Tags: tensorflow

```py
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

def add_to_batch(image):

    print('Adding to batch')
    image_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image],batch_size=5,capacity=11,min_after_dequeue=1,num_threads=1)

    # Add to summary
    tf.image_summary('images',image_batch)

    return image_batch

def get_batch():

    # Create filename queue of images to read
    filenames = [('/media/jessica/Jessica/TensorFlow/Practice/unlabeled_data_%d.png' % i) for i in range(11)]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # Read and process image
    my_image = tf.image.decode_png(value)
    my_image_float = tf.cast(my_image,tf.float32)
    image_mean = tf.reduce_mean(my_image_float)
    my_noise = tf.random_normal([96,96,3],mean=image_mean)
    my_image_noisy = my_image_float + my_noise
    print('Reading images')

    return add_to_batch(my_image_noisy)

def main ():

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/media/jessica/Jessica/TensorFlow/Practice/summary_logs', graph_def=sess.graph_def)
    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    images = get_batch()
    summary_str = sess.run(merged)
    writer.add_summary(summary_str)
```

Hi,

I am trying to build a simple neural network in TensorFlow. I am trying to load my input images in batches. Now I am testing the code with 11 images and batch_size = 5. Eventually I will be working with 100000 images.

This bit of code is modified from TensorFlow's cifar10.py example. For some reason my code stops (doesn't terminate, it just hangs there) at `tf.train.shuffle_batch([image],batch_size=5,capacity=1,min_after_dequeue=1,num_threads=1)`

I've tried different combinations of batch_size, capacity, min_after_dequeue etc. but I still can't figure out what is going wrong.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I edited your code to fix the indentation (otherwise the Python interpreter wouldn't accept it). Let me know if it's incorrect!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the problem arises because the statement

```
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
```

...executes before any queue runners have been created. If you move this line after `images = get_batch()`, your program should work.

What is the problem here? The [`tf.train.shuffle_batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch) function internally uses a [`tf.RandomShuffleQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#RandomShuffleQueue) to produce a randomized batch. Currently, the only way to get elements into that queue is to run a step that invokes the [`q.enqueue()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.enqueue) op. To make this easier, TensorFlow has a notion of ["queue runners"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html#queuerunner) that are implicitly collected as you build your graph, and then started with a call to `tf.train.start_queue_runners()`. However, calling `tf.train.start_queue_runners()` only starts the queue runners that have been defined at that point in time, so it must come **after** the code that creates the queue runners.